# OSB Java callout to core java class

Tags: osb, oracle-service-bus

I have a simple java call out to decode a base64 string. The java looks like this

```
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public final class DecodeBase64 {
    public static byte[] decode(String base64string) {
        return DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(base64string);
    }
}
```

Then I was thinking that since `DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary` is static why not call it directly. This way I can avoid having to deploy my jar.

I cannot however seem to find a way to call a core java class from the OSB java callout.

Is this possible? Is it even feasible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it would be possible to make that, as you can see from the documentation on [Java Callouts](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/doc.1111/e15867/proxy_actions.htm#i1321171), you first need to specify the .jar that you will use to make the callout.  There's likely a ton of existing libraries, etc., in the classpath in OSB that Oracle et al wouldn't want to blindly expose, but I think you should be able to import and use in a .jar pretty easily.

[Section 21.20 - Adding Java Callouts](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/doc.1111/e15867/proxy_actions.htm#i1321171) - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/doc.1111/e15867/proxy_actions.htm#i1321171

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking to do Base64 conversion for setting Basic authorization while calling an external system or validating the input authorization header, then OSB has an inbuilt feature called "Service Accounts" which when combined with Business services / proxy services can convert your username / password into a Base64 format.

if you are looking to convert data into Base64 format for some other reason, then i am afraid, you cannot do so in OSB without making a java callout.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible . You have to import the jar